# Get meteor to unsubscribe from data

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm not sure if this is possible due to the way meteor works. I'm trying to figure out how to unsubscribe and subscribe to collections and have the data removed from mini mongo on the client side when the user clicks a button. The problem I have in the example below is that when a user clicks the `handleButtonAllCompanies` all the data is delivered to the client and then if they click `handleButtonTop100` it doesn't resubscribe. So the data on the client side doesn't change. Is it possible to do this?

Path: `CompaniesPage.jsx`

```
export default class CompaniesPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleButtonAllCompanies = this.handleButtonAllCompanies.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonTop100 = this.handleButtonTop100.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonAllCompanies(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    Meteor.subscribe('companiesAll');
  }

  handleButtonTop100(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    Meteor.subscribe('companiesTop100');
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(1, this.props.companiesASX);
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleButtonAllCompanies}>All</Button>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleButtonTop100}>Top 100</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `Publish.js`

```
Meteor.publish('admin.handleButtonAllCompanies', function() {
  return CompaniesASX.find({});
});

Meteor.publish('admin.handleButtonTop100', function() {
  return CompaniesASX.find({}, { limit: 100});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first thanks to @Christian Fritz, his suggestion got me onto the right track. I hope this helps someone else.

I didn't realise that subscriptions should be controlled within the Container component, not in the page component. By using `Session.set` and `Session.get` I'm able to update the Container component which updates the subscription.

This works (if there is a better or more meteor way please post) and I hope this helps others if they come across a similar problem.

Path `CompaniesContainer.js`

```
export default UploadCSVFileContainer = withTracker(({ match }) => {
  const limit = Session.get('limit');

  const companiesHandle = Meteor.subscribe('companies', limit);
  const companiesLoading = !companiesHandle.ready();
  const companies = Companies.find().fetch();
  const companiesExists = !companiesLoading && !!companies;

  return {
    companiesLoading,
    companies,
    companiesExists,
    showCompanies: companiesExists ? Companies.find().fetch() : []
  };
})(UploadCSVFilePage);
```

Path: `CompaniesPage.jsx`

```
export default class CompaniesPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleButtonAllCompanies = this.handleButtonAllCompanies.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonTop100 = this.handleButtonTop100.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonAllCompanies(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // mongodb limit value of 0 is equivalent to setting no limit
    Session.set('limit', 0)
  }

  handleButtonTop100(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set('limit', 100)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleButtonAllCompanies}>All</Button>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleButtonTop100}>Top 100</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `Publish.js`

```
Meteor.publish('companies', function() {
  if (limit || limit === 0) {
    return Companies.find({}, { limit: limit });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible, but the way to do that is to fix your publication. You want to think MVC, i.e., separate as much as possible the data and mode from the way you are going to present it. This means that you should not maintain two publications of the same collection, for two specific purposes. Rather you want to reuse the same publication, but just change the parameters as needed.

```js
Meteor.publish('companies', function(limit) {
  if (limit) {
    return CompaniesASX.find({}, { limit });
  } else { 
    return CompaniesASX.find({});
  }
});
```

Then you can define your button handlers as:

```js
  handleButtonAllCompanies(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.subscribe('companies');
  }

  handleButtonTop100(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.subscribe('companies', 100);
  }
```

This way you are changing an existing subscription, rather than creating a new one.

I'm not yet super familiar with react in meteor. But in blaze you wouldn't even need to re-subscribe. You would just provide a reactive variable as the subscription parameter and whenever that would change, meteor would update the subscription reactively. The same may be possible in react, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Thanks for this. I assume the problem is with react. The client doesn't update. If i click top100 and then all, the client side collection updates, however, if I reverse it and click all then top100 it doesn't remove the data on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Path CompaniesContainer.js

```
export default CompaniesContainer = withTracker(() => {
  let companiesHandle;  // or fire subscribe here if you want the data to be loaded initially
  const getCompanies = (limit) => {
    companiesHandle = Meteor.subscribe('companies', limit);
  }

  return {
    getCompanies,
    companiesLoading: !companiesHandle.ready(),
    companies: Companies.find().fetch(),
  };
})(CompaniesPage);
```

Path: CompaniesPage.jsx

```
export default class CompaniesPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleButtonAllCompanies = this.handleButtonAllCompanies.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonTop100 = this.handleButtonTop100.bind(this);
  }

  getCompanies(limit) {
    this.props.getCompanies(limit);
  }

  handleButtonAllCompanies(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // mongodb limit value of 0 is equivalent to setting no limit
    this.getCompanies(0);
  }

  handleButtonTop100(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.getCompanies(100);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleButtonAllCompanies}>All</Button>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleButtonTop100}>Top 100</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: Publish.js

```
Meteor.publish('companies', function(limit) {
  if (!limit) { limit = 0; }
  return Companies.find({}, { limit: limit });
});
```

Comment: Is it better to use this than session?

Comment: I get an error in the controller. `Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined`. I assume this is from `companiesLoading: !companiesHandle.ready(),`

Comment: @bp123 yes you shouldn't *ever* need to use Session, if you are its a sign you aren't taking the right approach. I have built a couple of reasonably sized sites using Meteor + react and only used Session once for modal control, but then refactored it out using this.state. Yes sorry that error will be from when _companiesHandle_ hasn't been initialised, I didn't have time to test code. you'll need something like companiesLoading: companiesHandle && !companiesHandle.ready()

Comment: Thanks that fixed the companiesHandle problem, however, the original issue still remains with this solution. Once the data has been pushed to the client it isn't removed. IE. I click show all then click top100. Is something missing?

Comment: hey @bp123 I'm happy to take a look - but need to see your entire component and how its rendering.  Please feel free to email me directly (see my profile). cheers